# Fetch API- res.json() returns an [object][object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, passport.js

I've tried a lot of solutions I found, but with no success. I'm fetching the **user** object after authenticating-

**Login.jsx-**

```
const login = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
    });
        
    const data = await res.json();
    
    console.log('data: ' + data); // [object][object]
}
```

**routes.js**

```
const handleLoginPost = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(404).json({err});
            return;
        }

        res.status(200).json(user);
        return;

    })(req, res, next);
}

router.post('/login', handleLoginPost);
```

When I use `res.text()` instead `res.json()` then it returns a string object-

```
{"_id":"5f72cf2aa985f40488b2eb2b","username":"sapinder","email":"1@gmail.com","hash":"$2b$10$/7lYBHWP1Ed2VXXSIizyiOk.aujvbi2iRRrFxy6ufxu..S81oRl2u","__v":0}
```

It's a string because `typeof data` returns String in this case. I tried `JSON.parse(data)` but it again returns `[object][object]`.

What's the correct method to extract the **user** object?

Comment: res.status(200).json(user); try printing value of user here

Comment: Also try res.send() and check what it is returing

Comment: Change `console.log('data: ' + data)` to this `console.log('data: ',  data)` or to this: `console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))`.   Your `console.log()` was triggering a default string conversion of `data`.  In Javascript, the default string conversion for an object is `[Object object]` which is useless.  Your data is there, it's just your `console.log()` code that is faulty when trying to output it.

Comment: @jfriend00 OMG! I can't believe I missed on that part! Thanks for correcting! It works now!

Comment: @Sapinder - I posted an answer below with that same info in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
console.log('data: ' + data)
```

to this

```
console.log('data: ',  data)
```

or to this:

```
console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)).
```

Your `console.log()` was triggering a default string conversion of data. In Javascript, the default string conversion for an object is `[Object object]` which is generally useless. Your data is there, it's just your `console.log()` code that is faulty when trying to output it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try with `.then(data => console.log('data: ' + data))`

Comment: I did this before changing to `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
const login = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
    }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
  });

  console.log("Res", res)
  return res;
}
```